# Solve set of nonlinear equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

I am looking for solving this set of nonlinear equation. 
\begin{aligned}
2q_1q_3 - 2q_2q_4&=a_1\\
-2q_1q_2 - 2q_3q_4&=a_2\\
- q_1^2 + q_2^2 + q_3^2 - q_4^2&=a3\\
q_1^2 + q_2^2 + q_3^2 + q_4^2&=1\\
\end{aligned}
hint:This is IMU quaternion output!

Any Help would be appreciated.
Using  @FanZheng hint equation would change into 
\begin{aligned}
z_1z_2&=\frac{a_1}{2}-i\frac{a_2}{2}\\
|z_1|^2-|z_2|^2&=-a_3\\
|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2&=1
\end{aligned}
more simple
\begin{aligned}
z_1z_2&=\frac{a_1}{2}-i\frac{a_2}{2}\\
|z_1|^2&=\frac{1-a_3}{2}\\
|z_2|^2&=\frac{1+a_3}{2}
\end{aligned}

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: The hint is probably an overkill. Try think about the complex numbers $z_1=q_1+iq_4$ and $z_2=q_3+iq_2$ instead. (Of course I assume you are looking for real solutions.)

Comment: Thank you  @FanZheng but I would appreciate it if you give me the closed form. Your hint made equation a bit smaller but I have no idea how to continue

PS: I'm in hurry. :(

Comment: How about Newton's method for multivariate ?

Comment: Use the last two equations for the magnitudes of $z_1$ and $z_2$ first.

Comment: Still looking for solution

Comment: @V.Ajall This problem is a little unusual in the sense that not every tuple $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ will give rise to a solution, and when it does, there are infinitely many of them. To understand this situation, try solve the system $$ z_1z_2=A,\ |z_1|^2=B,\ |z_2|^2=C $$ and see what happens.

Comment: I know that this system has 8 solution

Comment: @V.Ajall How do you know that?

Comment: @FanZheng Our teacher said. (might be wrong)

Comment: @V.Ajall That's definitely incorrect. Because of the identity $|z_1z_2|^2=|z_1|^2|z_2|^2$, the system has a solution only when $A^2=BC$. If that holds, then from $|z_1|^2=B$ you know that $z_1$ can be any complex number of modulus $\sqrt B$. If $z_1$ is given, then from $z_1z_2=A$ you can solve for $z_2$. If you put that in the third equation, you will find that $|z_2|^2=C$ automatically holds, so there are infinitely many solutions, one for each possible value of $z_1$. Of course I have been assuming that $A\neq0$, $B\neq0$ and $C\neq0$. Otherwise the situation is more complicated.

Comment: @FanZheng Consider $q_1=\pm 1,q_2=q_3=q_4=0$ which is one of the answers.
Also consider  $q_1=q_2=q_3=0,q_4=\pm 1$. these four places will lead into one system equation. which is my problem. so at the same time the system has 4 different solution and in other case it has 8 solution which can be inferred from initial value.